# Como verificar a zona de tempo do Windows em tempo real, usando Python?

Tags: python, time

Estou tentando pegar a zona de tempo do sistema em tempo real usando Python, fiz o código abaixo:

```
import tzlocal
tzlocal.get_localzone().zone
```

O problema é que, ao alterar o zona de tempo do Windows o código continua pegando a mesma zona de tempo, ou seja, abro o IDLE do Python e executo o código, altero a zona de tempo no Windows e executo o código novamente na mesma janela do IDLE e continuo recebendo o mesmo resultado de antes de alterar a zona de tempo.

Como poderia dar um "refresh", sem ter que fechar e abrir o IDLE?

Answer (score 4):

Essa biblioteca `localtz`  não é parte do Python - ela é código aberto, e o código dela está aqui:

https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal

Felizmente é um código razoavelmente simples, que só faz o trabalho de codificar as chamadas para cada sistema operacional, pegar a informação de TZ "bruta", e converter num formato usável pelo Python

Navegando no código até a parte que pega a timzone no Windows, nessa URL, chegamos nessa função:

https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal/blob/master/tzlocal/win32.py

```py
def get_localzone():
    """Returns the zoneinfo-based tzinfo object that matches the Windows-configured timezone."""
    global _cache_tz
    if _cache_tz is None:
        _cache_tz = ZoneInfo(get_localzone_name())

    utils.assert_tz_offset(_cache_tz)
    return _cache_tz
```

E aí fica aparente por que a atualização não acontece: ele essa essa variável de cache depois da primeira chamada.

Aí, você tem duas opções: pode fazer a replicar a chamada que ele faz ali no seu código:

```
from tzlocal.win32 import Zoneinfo, get_localzone_name

ZoneInfo(get_localzone_name())
```

Ou, antes de cada chamada ao `get_localzone()` você apaga o cache explicitamente:

```
import tzlocal.win32

tzlocal.win32._cache_tz = None
```

Ambas as formas vão funcionar - mas você tem que ter em mente que: você está usando a parte diretamente relacionada a Windows - se quiser que o seu programa seja independente do sistema operacional, precisa checar e fazer as operações equivalentes no `unix.py` - e, segundo, que está usand uma forma que não é oficialmente documentada no pacote - então está sujeito a esse código ser alterado em outra versão do tzlocal, e seu código pode parar de funcionar. Essa segunda parte se resolve "pinando" a versão no seu projeto, se for um projeto completo: você determina quais versões do tzlocal são aceitas, explicitamente.

Só para ficar completa a resposta: do lado "unix" (Linux e Mac OS) é a mesma coisa, tem-se que zerar a variável de cache em

```
import tzlocal.unix
uniz._tz_cache = None

tzlocal.get_localzone()
```

Comment: Obrigado, porem quando faço como sugerido é retornado um erro. ValueError: Timezone offset does not match system offset: -10800 != -14400. Please, check your config files.

Comment: bom - esse erro certamente é por conta daquela chamada ao `utils.assert_tz_offset(_cache_tz)` - tem que descer no código dele (não consigo agora). Se em vez de apagar o cache, você chama ro `ZoneInfo`  o erro acontece também? 
(a chance é que a lib tenha mais uma variável de cache em outro módulo, por isso o erro)